# iOS - Notification Service Extension will be killed due to sluggish startup

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I have an issue starting a Notification Service Extension. After distributing the app via TestFlight certain phones had a high rate of failure to start the extension and it fails with the following log message:

`default  10:13:56.071211 +0100   SpringBoard [xxx.Notification-Service] Beginning extension session...
error   10:13:57.072210 +0100   SpringBoard [xxx.Notification-Service] Extension will be killed due to sluggish startup
default 10:13:57.074178 +0100   SpringBoard [xxx] Deliver push notification request 50E3-E564
error   10:13:57.074550 +0100   SpringBoard Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named xxx.Notification-Service" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named xxx.Notification-Service}`

The error message suggests that it takes too long to start the extension (note the nearly exact 1000ms between beginning and killing the extension).

What I did try was that I eliminated all dynamic dependencies and added them directly to my extension target.
Also a rewrite of the extension in ObjC (to not have to link against Swift libraries) did not solve the issue.

Did somebody else experienced such behaviour or has an idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: did you find the solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seemed that attaching the debugger to the Notification Service Extension caused a slow start of the extension.

You have to attach the debugger after the first push message arrived. This way it also shows up as debuggable process under `Debug -> Attach to process -> "Your Notification Extension"`